# CSV dataframe doesn't match with dataframe generated from URL

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file that I download from NERL API. When I try to compare it with older csv I get a difference using  `.equals` command in padas but both files are 100% same. the only difference is one data frame is generated from CSV and another is directly from API URL.

Below is my code, why is there a difference?

```
import pandas as pd
NERL_url = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?api_key=DEMO_KEY&fuel_type=ELEC&country=all" 
outputPath = r"D:\<myPCPath>\nerl.csv"
urlDF = pd.read_csv(NERL_url, low_memory=False)
urlDF.to_csv(outputPath, header=True,index=None, encoding='utf-8-sig')

csv_df = pd.read_csv(outputPath, low_memory=False)  


if csv_df.equals(urlDF):
    print("Same")
else:
    print("Different")
```

My output is coming as `Different`. How do I fix this and why is this difference comming?

Comment: What is `print (csv_df.eq(urlDF))` ?

Comment: It's `False` in my terminal

Comment: I expected huge boolean dataframe, are you sure there is False?

Comment: My bad, yes, it's a data frame that has some true and false values. I don't know why since there are no difference in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is precision in `read_csv`, set to `float_precision='round_trip'` and then compared `NaN`s values, need replaced them to same values, like `same`:

```
NERL_url = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.csv?api_key=DEMO_KEY&fuel_type=ELEC&country=all"
```

---

```
outputPath = r"nerl.csv"
urlDF = pd.read_csv(NERL_url, low_memory=False)
urlDF.to_csv(outputPath, header=True,index=None, encoding='utf-8-sig')

csv_df = pd.read_csv(outputPath, low_memory=False, float_precision='round_trip')  


if csv_df.fillna('same').equals(urlDF.fillna('same')):
    print("Same")
else:
    print("Different")
    
Same
```

Comment: I am getting `same column` and `same index` as output and the third snippet just gives the entire data frame as output. I still don't understand why it's showing the difference for basically the same date and how do I fix this

Comment: @PrashantKumar - added last solution, what is difference `print (s1[s1 != s2])

print (s2[s1 != s2])` ?

Comment: @jerael Here is the output of the snippet you added. It just shows the entire data frame , here are the images    https://ibb.co/PMk6BLy    and    https://ibb.co/S5sHqhV

Comment: Also if possible, please try to run it once your system at least once.. I am sure it would replicate on your system too

Comment: @PrashantKumar - How I can run your solution? If I have no file and no access to API?

Comment: It's a free api (you don't need any api key), you can run it as is. All you need is python, pandas and update the path of  `outputPath`  to one of your local folder and add a `nerl.csv` at the end of it in the script @jezrael

Comment: @PrashantKumar - Is possible sent me API key ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241651/discussion-between-prashant-kumar-and-jezrael).

Comment: @PrashantKumar - answer was edited.